# Responding to and sending asynchronous GET requests

Tags: php

I want to make an application that will be receiving get requests and respond with xml.
Here's the scenario:

User comes to site_a.com?site.phpid=abc, from there I have to make a GET request to site_b.com/checker.php?id=abc.

How to make a GET request without user leaving the page?

Inside checker.php I have to respond with xml depending on that id

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  if($_GET['id']=='abc'){
    // respond with xml
 }
}
```

and then is site.php I have to receive that xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easist way, you could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
//site.php?id=abc
$xmlResponse = file_get_contents("site_b.com/checker.php?id=abc");
```

But make sure `allow_url_fopen` can be true.
http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use `curl`.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site_b.com/checker.php?id=' . $id); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$xml = curl_exec(); 
curl_close($ch);
```

[curl docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)